# jQuery resizable destroyin the structure of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a structure of divs:
html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
    <head>
        <title>Test Area</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div id="resizable" class="tile" style="background-color: darkblue"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css file "stylesheet.css":

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}
.tile {
    width:100%;
    min-height:25px;
    background-color: palegreen;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.tile:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I want the one with the id "resizable" to resize only in y axis (down). If I resize it more than a half of the next div height, I want the next div to disappear and the resizable one to resize in order to fill the freed space (number of divs to disappear sums up). The height of (div of class) box should be unchanged during this process. Here is my jQuery code "scripts.js":

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        containment: "parent",
        handles: "s",
        ghost: true,
        grid: [0, 26], //25 height + 1 border
        stop: function(event, ui){
            var before = ui.originalSize['height'];
            var after = ui.size['height'];
            if(after > before){
                var diff = after - before;
                var numberOfTiles = Math.round(diff/26);
                ui.element.css('height',before + numberOfTiles * 26 );
                ui.element.css('width','100%');
                var object = $(this);
                for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTiles; i++){
                    object = object.next();
                    object.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the resized div is standing out from the (div of class) box. I don't know what is the cause that.